# Cambiar de pantalla ( Boton toolboard )

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Tengo la siguiente parte de mi código:

```
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) { 
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.barra_superior, menu);  // toolboard
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle presses on the action bar items
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.search:
                openSearch();
                return true;
            case R.id.add:
                openAdd();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

He creado un menú y al darle al boton add

debería ser algo así:

```
 private  void openAdd() {

        final Button buttonAdd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add);
           buttonAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), inserir_Llibre.class);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 0);

            }
        });

    }
```

Pero no me funciona, solo he cambiado de pantallas con botones, y veo que por el toolboard funciona diferente y no sé como hacerlo funcionar.

Me ayudáis?

gracias!

Comment: has probado a cambiar v.getContext() por getContext() o por getApplicationContext(); ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Me parece que lo querés es que `openAdd()` abra el activity `inserir_Llibre.class`.

En ese caso, y asumiendo que `this` es un `Activity` porque el método `openAdd()` forma parte del `Activity` el método sería:

```
private  void openAdd() {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, inserir_Llibre.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 0);

}
```

Si hay otro botón en la interface de usuario que te permite hacer lo mismo entonces, en `onCreate()`, sí le seteas el `OnClickListener`, pero que llame a la misma función para no duplicar código.

En onCreate():

```
...
final Button botonAddDeLayout= (Button) findViewById(R.id.botonAddDeLayout);
botonAddDeLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            openAdd();
        }
 });
...
```

Comment: gracias!!!!!!! ^^

Answer (score 0):

**No debes crear el listener dentro de la acción "clic" de tu botón**, esto es incorrecto ya que cuando desees usar el listener del botón (buttonAdd) este no funcionará si no has llamado previamente el método `openAdd()`.

```
private  void openAdd() {

        final Button buttonAdd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add);
           buttonAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), inserir_Llibre.class);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 0);

            }
        });

    }
```

La solución es agregar únicamente la acción dentro del método `openAdd()`

```
private  void openAdd() {
   //*Acción!
   Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), inserir_Llibre.class);
   startActivityForResult(intent, 0);            
}
```

y en `onCreate()` de tu Activity define tu listener después de `setContentView()` :

```
private Button buttonAdd;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ...
    ...
       buttonAdd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add);
       buttonAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           //*Llama método!               
           openAdd();
        }
    });
   ...
   ...
}
```